# Intresting puzzle

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

***Task definition:***

I have a matrix of natural numbers. The task is to find path from the top-left corner of matrix to bottom-right corner of matrix and dial maximum score.
Rules of navigation: if you are located in [i][j] you can move:
a) to [i][j-1], [i][j+1], [i+1][j] cells and dial zero points
b) to [i+1][j+1] and dial matrix[i][j] points

***Little example:***

Assume you have `score 50`and `matrix`

```
0 3 5 3 2
4 7 2 5 2
4 3 5 2 5
```

Assume you are in [1][1] cell (matrix[1][1] = 7). You can navigate to:

```
a) [1][0] cell with 50 score
b) [1][2] cell with 50 score
c) [2][1] cell with 50 score
d) [2][2] cell with 57 score
```

***What a problem:***

I solve this task in very slow way...

I try to implement in with help of recursion. It's easy if you just want to find maximum score. Something like

```
public int loop(int i, int j) {
  int left = loop(i, j-1);
  int top = loop(i-1, j);
  int diagonal = loop(i-1,j-1) + matrix[i-1][j-1];
  return maximum(left, top, diagonal);
}
```

**BUT, I want to find a path with maximum score! And it's very time/memory consuming.**

*Why it's time/memory consuming:*

And there is one problem: I need store path-collection and pass it as a parameter to the loop method. But loop method forks on each iteration and I have to copy path-collection thee times an iteration. Otherwise, each of loop forks will modify common path-collection and finally I will have in it all possible paths. I mean if between `left`, `top` & `diagonal` the biggest is `left` that we must not to include paths linked with `top` and `diagonal`.

***Question:***

*How to solve it in right way?*

***EDIT:***

Actually there is no need to find the full path. It only need to find point's in which you dial a score (in which you make a diagonal moves)

Comment: The task here is simply to move to the cell with the highest score for each value of `[i]`.  It's not that hard.

Comment: Greedy algo must work fine. Just find maximum for each line

Comment: What if it bounces back and forth given the `[i][j-1]`, `[i][j+1]` transitions from `[i][j]`?

Comment: @user568109 - just don't generate those moves.  They don't net any points anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You don't need dynamic programming nor brute force for this!**

To see why, let's analyze the rules:

- You can move in direction `j` freely (left & right), so there's no reason to be careful about that direction - you can move into the optimial horizontal postion whenever you want.
- Once you increase `i` (down) there's no way back (though you can increase `i` without gaining points).  Each increase of `i` should net the maximal amount of points.
- You gain points by *leaving* a cell, but you can only ever leave a row once.
- **That means you can subdivide this problem and do not need dynamic programming**: you can move to the optimal `j` location, then take one diagonal step; repeat until done.
- The optimal `i` step is moving from a non-last cell in a row with the highest value.  You can't move from the last cell because there's no diagonal move possible - so if your matrix has only one column (or row for that matter) you'll never gain points.  You can't lose points because the values are natural numbers (but if negative numbers were allowed, you can still skip a row).

In more detail, the optimal path is then found by...

1. Does the matrix have just one column or row?  Move right repeatedly without gaining points then end the program.  You can't do much here.
2. find the maximum value in the current row, ignoring the last value.
3. generate 'j' moves towards a maximally-valued cell, then move diagonally.
4. If you're not on the last row, go back to step 2.
5. You're on the last row and cannot gain more points; just generate moves towards the bottom-right corner to finish your path.

That's it!

Note that there may be multiple maximal paths, your problem specification doesn't guarantee a unique solution.

**EDIT:**  If you don't need the actual path, but just the numbers you scored, the algorithm is much easier - remove or disregard the last row and last column, then for each `i` (row) return the maximum value in that row.

Comment: If all of the values in the current row are negative you'll want to just take the free move down. Otherwise I agree with this solution.

Comment: @EricBarr: Natural numbers are non-negative.

Comment: Oh whoops I missed that requirement in the question. My bad!

Comment: Hey, I like the version with negative numbers better anyhow.  It's a nice and nasty little trap :-).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
I misread the question to being just moving down and to the right (ie: `j` could only change to `j` or `j+1`.) so this answer is wrong.

You can use dynamic programming to solve this problem. Greedy doesn't exactly work because you can only travel "down and to the right".

The naive dynamic programming solution would essentially "work backwards" in a literal sense and start from the bottom-right and compute max score when starting at that cell.

Starting from the right-left, and from bottom-up, you can compute the best score you can get from that score simply. You do this for the `m x n` matrix, then you start from the top left and choose the direction that has the max score.